Plumbing Issues
This is part 59 of the puzzle series Around the World in Many Days. Each part is solvable on its own.

Dear Puzzling,
This is a Pipes puzzle (also known as Net, FreeNet and NetWalk). Rotate some cells in the grid so that the lines form a single connected network. Closed loops are allowed, but all parts must be connected to each other.
Now, normally this puzzle type works by rotating cells as indicated above. However, I ran into some problems trying to make that work technically for the editable grid. So instead there’s an equivalent puzzle in the bottom grid with different mechanics. Draw horizontal and vertical lines connecting centres of cells so that the lines form a single connected network and the lines entering each cell match the cell type indicated in the cell (1 for “one end”, 2S for “two ends going straight”, 2T for “two ends turning”, or 3 for “three ends” – see examples at the bottom right). You can choose to solve either variation – either the bottom one using the solve link below, or the top one using whichever method you prefer. However, do note that the grey letters leading to the final answer are only present in the top grid.
Today I have travelled by boat to see a large collection of religious sculptures. Can you guess where I am?
Love, Gladys.
PS. Added after the fact: The intention was that loop ends must be centres of cells. This is evident if you use the solve link, but is not mentioned in the rules listed above. Sorry about that!

Solve on Penpa+

Gladys will return in Breaking New Ground.

Simon Tatham's puzzle link for online solving.

@DanielMathias Awesome, thanks for that!

@DanielMathias Be careful of a subtle rule difference: loops are allowed in this puzzle, but not in Simon Tatham's.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That isn't really relevant. The closed-loop rule is clearly stated, and Simon Tatham's puzzle app is merely a tool to aid in solving.

If you've got plumbing issues, could be an old folk's home.

Gladys is at

 PAK OU CAVES

This is the completed grid:

 

Then

 Eliminate the letters in the tiles where you have turned the lines on the grid:
 


 This leads to the remaining letters being PAKOUCAVES reading from left to right.

Solution path for the grid:

 Start off with the obvious deductions first in R1C1 this turn is needed forcing the alteration of R3C1:
 


 Now because the lines need to form a single connected network and there is only one way to prevent loose ends in R4C1, R4C2 is forced to face the line like so. R3C2 cannot change as it would create loose ends so the turn in R2C2 is forced. R1C3 is then altered in order to allow the line in R1C2 to be joined to the rest of the lines:
 


 Turns in R3C3 and so R4C3 is then necessitated:
 


 The necessitated turns in R1C4 and R3C4 forces this configuration. Start with turning R2C4 afterwards and rest should be pretty obvious:
 


 Which then forces this because of the needed turn in R4C7 forcing turns in R4C6 and R5C7 which then forces the rest:
 


 There is then only one way then to connect R7C7 to the rest of the grid. Also the turns in R7C4 and R6C4 are forced:
 


 The turn in R6C3 is forced basically and there is only one configuration possible for R7C2. This then forces:
 


 To finish off we just need to turn R4C4 and R5C4 in a way that ties off any loose ends like so:
 

